# Angular2 timeout in http post request

Tags: http, post, angular

Is it possible to make a timeout of 3 seconds in a post request ? How ?

My code for the moment

```
this.http.post('myUrl', 
    MyData, {headers: Myheaders})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => this.ret = data,
            error => console.debug('ERROR', error),
            () => console.log('END')
        );
```

Comment: the http request gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after 4 minutes from sending the request. Is there any way to increase this time?. I tried the .timeout() method. But it still gives error after 4 minutes

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` operator like this:

```
this.http.post('myUrl', 
        MyData, {headers: Myheaders})
         .timeout(3000, new Error('timeout exceeded'))
         .map(res => res.json())
         .subscribe(
           data => this.ret = data,
           error => console.debug('ERROR', error),
           () => console.log('END')
         );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it doesn't work for me, it is always execute "return new Error('delay exceeded')"

Comment: Oh sorry! There was a typo in my answer. I updated it. If you could make a new try...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier instead of returning `new Error` we should throw an error `throw new Error` so that you can see that error in console with actual `red color`

Comment: @PankajParkar Nope, instead of reading it with console.debug we should throw it.
Anyway it's passing the error as an argument to the function. if you throw there it's a syntax error, and would always throw, not only on timeouts.

Comment: what kind of timeout of above? Connection timeout? Socket timeout? Looks like it's only an observable timeout. What I'm confused is that if server properly handled the response and returned to client more than 2000 millseconds, what's happened then?

Answer (score 23):

You might need to import timeout like so

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'`

I couldn't get it to work without that on rxjs `5.0.1` and angular `2.3.1`

**Edit 20 April 2018**

please refrain from importing operators that way, in rxjs +5.5 you can import operators like this one with

```
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators/timeout';
// Use it like so
stream$.pipe(timeout(3000))
```

Please checkout [this](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) document which explains pipeable operators in great depth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it needs to be imported for angular 5+

Answer (score 13):

I modified the answer of Thierry to get it working with the latest release. It is necessary to remove the second parameter of the timeout function. According to a discussion regarding an angular-cli issue, the timeout function always throws a TimeoutError now.

```
this.http.post('myUrl', 
    MyData, {headers: Myheaders})
     .timeout(3000)
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(
       data => this.ret = data,
       error => console.debug('ERROR', error),
       () => console.log('END')
     );
```

Comment: Confirmed that an error can't be passed as the second argument in Angular 4